# Identify rows in 2nd dataframe having values less than the first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as shown in the code below. The dates are the same in both of them. I need to be able to identify the values in the second dataframe that are less than the first for the same date. Based on the data, I should get 1/1/2008 with the value of 33, 1/4/2008 with 35 etc since it is less than the corresponding value in the first dataframe. I am able to get a boolean value, but am unable to get the actual values from the second dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'Date': {1: '1/1/2008',
  2: '1/2/2008',
  3: '1/3/2008',
  4: '1/4/2008',
  5: '1/5/2008',
  6: '1/6/2008',
  7: '1/7/2008',
  8: '1/8/2008',
  9: '1/9/2008',
 10: '1/10/2008'
   },
 'windspeed': {1: '36',
  2: '38',
  3: '40',
  4: '39',
  5: '45',
  6: '33',
  7: '31',
  8: '39',
  9: '41',
 10: '37'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Date': {1: '1/1/2008',
  2: '1/2/2008',
  3: '1/3/2008',
  4: '1/4/2008',
  5: '1/5/2008',
  6: '1/6/2008',
  7: '1/7/2008',
  8: '1/8/2008',
  9: '1/9/2008',
 10: '1/10/2008'
  },
 'windspeed': {1: '33',
  2: '39',
  3: '42',
  4: '35',
  5: '43',
  6: '40',
  7: '39',
  8: '37',
  9: '44',
 10: '35'}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the index (for alignment) and compare -

```
i = df1.set_index('Date')
j = df2.set_index('Date')

j[i.windspeed > j.windspeed]

          windspeed
Date               
1/1/2008         33
1/4/2008         35
1/5/2008         43
1/8/2008         37
1/10/2008        35
```

If the date columns are *not identical*, you could use `align` first -

```
i, j = i.align(j)
```

Then, repeat the same comparison + filtration step. If you want the `Date` as another column, call `reset_index` on the result -

```
j[i.windspeed > j.windspeed].reset_index()

        Date windspeed
0   1/1/2008        33
1   1/4/2008        35
2   1/5/2008        43
3   1/8/2008        37
4  1/10/2008        35
```

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. That is what I was looking for. Quick question. If I don't care about the dates, how do I go about dropping that column?

Comment: @rajeev You'll need `j[i.windspeed > j.windspeed].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.windspeed=df1.windspeed.astype(int)
df2.windspeed=df2.windspeed.astype(int)
df1.set_index('Date').windspeed.gt(df2.set_index('Date').windspeed)
Out[247]: 
Date
1/1/2008      True
1/2/2008     False
1/3/2008     False
1/4/2008      True
1/5/2008      True
1/6/2008     False
1/7/2008     False
1/8/2008      True
1/9/2008     False
1/10/2008     True
Name: windspeed, dtype: bool
```

Update

```
df1[df1.set_index('Date').windspeed.gt(df2.set_index('Date').windspeed).values]
Out[250]: 
         Date  windspeed
1    1/1/2008         36
4    1/4/2008         39
5    1/5/2008         45
8    1/8/2008         39
10  1/10/2008         37
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was getting before. Just needed the lesser ones with values